# fast vnc alternative

Tags: vnc, teamviewer

I would like to some how be able to view and control a mac mini from a pc (locally). As I work with animations I need the connection to be extremely fast. I have tried using both VNC and Team Viewer over a local network , but they are both far too slow. Is there a faster way to view and control a osx device from windows? Perhaps there is some type of cable or gizmo I could buy.

Cheers

Edit:

At the moment I'm thinking I might be able to buy a laptop that supports HDMI input and run the mac mini display through that. Then I will just need to something to control the keys and mouse. Any idea's?

Comment: Give UltraVNC a try if not yet. You definitely don't want to use TeamViewer for this. Why not use the mini directly?

Comment: I need to travel and would love to access the mac mini from my windows laptop. Don't really want to spend money on a mac book if I don't have to.

Comment: Oh, I mean attach a monitor, keyboard and mouse to the mac mini. However, when you are travelling, VNC is almost your only choice.

Answer (score 2):

I've not tried it on a OS X system, but the current version of [nomachine](http://www.nomachine.com/), nomachine 4 seems to be perfectly usable over an edge or 3g connection, as well as wireless lan. Its pretty simple to install and use, and least to me seems massively responsive. It does occationally degrade colour depth over slower connections, but video seems pretty fluid to me.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the comments in your questions, there is no real way to get VNC to play animations very smoothly. VNC basically takes screenshots of your desktop and slings them over the network.

The fastest way I could imagine for you to get higher framerates is to lower the resolution, lower the bit of colors (24 bit down to 8bit), use compression (im not sure if mac os x vnc server supports that) and connect using ethernet.